Dynamically set variable in a batch file, where the variable name exists in another variable
I am sorta just seeing what is possible and what is not, when making batch files. I know it's quite a dated language but very interesting and still very functional.
I am surprised that I couldn't find anything when trying to look this up.
Here's my scenario:
I have two variables, one is called "varname" and contains a string, the other is "value" and contains an integer.
Without delayed expansion enabled, how can I change a variable that exists inside my script, which has the same name as the contents of the "varname" variable, and set the contents of that variable to equal the contents of "value".
Here's a small sample to demonstrate my thinking, let's say %%a contains the number 1000 and %%b contains the string "testvar":
set "testvar="
<input.txt set /p input=
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%a in ("%input%") do (
    set value=%%a
    set varname=%%b
)

--What to do next?--
set %varname%=%value%                 ...nope
set %%varname%%=%value%               ...nope
set %varname%=%%value%%               ...also nope

--call set? quotation marks? what is the magic combo to get this working (if there is one?)
So that I can do this, and it returns 1000:
echo %testvar%

Apparently you can do something special via "call set", but all the examples I've seen are people trying to set a hard wired variable name with a dynamic value. Nothing is of difficulty when you have delayed expansion, but in this instance I'm specifically looking for a way without it. If it's not possible, fair enough, but I'd be surprised.

I don't remember if there is a good way devised later, but originally naive users wrote the variable name and operation and value out into a (batch) file, and executed that file to run the operation on the variable with the value.

@user165568, oh hey, thanks for the reply. So far I had steered clear of making "helper batch files", but theoretically, how would that work? The helper file contains the value, variable name, and operation - and then what, you call the helper file from within your script? This somehow seems almost more inelegant than what I am thinking of. Because calling a subroutine to set a variable only works when you're not in a nested logic situation, the overhead is starting to become significant. Thanks anyway, because I had not considered this.

set "%varname%=%value%" will suffice if the name of the variable does not contain poison characters. Note, yoi won't be able to expand the value of testvar within the same parenthesised code block its defined without using Call echo %%testVar%% or by enabling and using delayed expansion

@T3RR0R, Dude... it works! I knew there was some silly combo I needed, this is awesome. So I have, inside a nested conditional, an interaction with a third party cli prog, I want to update one of my variables with that output. So i'm piping that output, as well as a relevant label, and the varname, to a text file. Immediately after, I use a goto to leave the nested conditional, and a small subroutine then reads the text file, delimits it into 3 parts, the value (from external prog), the variable name, and the label name. Variable is updated and script uses a goto to return back to where it was

@T3RR0R Sorry for the long comment, I just wanted to tell you what I was using this for. If you have a spare moment, would you care to weigh in, give two cents on whether this is highly stupid, or an adequate solution, like, is this something people have ever done before? etc. On an unrelated note, if you fleshed out your comment a little bit, maybe included the delayed expansion method too (even though I didn't ask, but it's informative for others), give a little code demo, etc. You could make a killer answer, and I'd mark it as the right solution, because I just tried it and it works!

Just try:
@echo off

set /p "_input=Enter two values separated by '-' : " 

 set "_value=%_input:*-=%"
set _varname=%_input:-=&echo/%

set %_varname%=%_value%
  set %_value%=%_varname%


variables | values
   _input==pizza-coke
   _value==coke
 _varname==pizza
     coke==pizza
    pizza==coke


Option to suppress output when assigning a variable name and value using the value of another variable.
@echo off

Set /p "_input=Enter two values separated by '-' : "


>nul =;(
       call set "_value=%_input:*-=%"
       call set _varname=%_input:-=&echo/%
     );=
     
>nul =;( 
      set _%_varname%=%_value%
      set _%_value%=%_varname%
     );= 

:: Just to check if they were properly defined, you can use...
set _ 


 Split string into substrings based on delimiter
Set variable=variable:substrings | DOS - String Manipulation


2>nul suppresses errors, and as for hiding real-time interactions in the console with the input command, yes, it’s possible. However, it involves much more complexity than intended for basic comment handling. This would be a separate question—likely already addressed in the community.

I don't know what to tell you. A code which uncontrollably prints to the console as part of some side-effect (which even @echo off doesn't suppress), is obviously not standard. Because I am on a learning journey, I appreciate it, but if it was me giving an answer, and I wanted to put a "cherry on top" of the answer via a useful bonus, I'd make sure that bonus doesn't have side-effects. If you didn't want me to ask about it, you could have easily just not included it :) But your answer is worthy on the basis of "set %_varname%=%_value" alone, so I will mark it as correct anyways! Thanks

The set /p command is designed to pause execution and prompt the user for data input. This behavior is normal and expected when using it, so any console output is an inherent part of the command.

You misunderstand, the set /p line is not a problem, and is entirely optional. This line is what causes an echoed statement undesirably: [set _varname=%_input:-=&echo/%], which is what I was saying, seems like a side-effect. I can do this: [set _varname=%_input:-=&/% 2>NUL] (remove the echo, and suppress errors, because removing the echo causes one), and retain full functionality. It's all well and good but I just don't have confidence in it. Let me know what you think... my only guess is maybe we're on different versions of Windows, and behavior of the interpretor is somehow different.

Now I understand you; please forgive my idiomatic shortcomings. See the edit.
